# Recalculate Custom VBA functions, Only on Request

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, user-defined-functions, commandbutton

**My Problem is this:**

I would like to use a custom ribbon Command button or even a simple command button inside the spreadsheet to initialize an OLEDB database connection and update/recalculate all the assoicated user defined functions that require such a connection, or those specified by me. I do not want any of these functions to recalculate except for when the specific button is clicked. I am having difficulty figuring out how to do this. Kindly offer your assistance or suggestions.

**See below for Details on what I have done:**

I currently store data within an access database from which I use vba in excel to make specific queries. I have embedded each datarequest routine within a group of functions under a module by the name [fnc]. I then access them as user-defined functions from within the excel spreadsheet. An example is given here:

```
 Function ValueV(mm As String, yy As String, qtable As String, qcode As String, compare_period As Integer, average_period As Integer, weight As Boolean) As Variant
 'Month Value Formula for Horizontal Data
 'mm - month value 2-digit
 'yy - year value 4-digit
 'qtable - query table name eg. "cpia"
 'qcode - query code for variable eg. "all0100"
 'avgperiod - lag periods to average in calculation eg. 3-avgperiods for quarterly measure, 1-avgperiod for point measure.
 'weight - boolean (true or false) value for weighting values given reference weight. Currently unsupported. Code should be extended to include this feature. (space holder for now)
  Dim lag_value As Variant
  Dim cur_value As Variant
  lag_value = 0
  cur_value = 0


     'STEP-A: Gets the initial Value average or not.
     '===============================================================
     If compare_period > 0 Then
     'Use this step to pickup initial value when compare_period <> 0 which requires a % change as opposed to a point value.
     'Average_period must be greater than or equal to one (1). One (1) represents the current month which is the same as a point value.
         lmm = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, compare_period, "mm")                          'lag month (a single month for mValueH)
         lyy = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, compare_period, "yy")                          'lag year (a single month for mValueH)
         smm = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, compare_period + average_period - 1, "mm")     'dating backwards to account for average period
         syy = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, compare_period + average_period - 1, "yy")     'dating backwards to account for average period
         'note, for smm & syy, the average period includes the lmm so we add back one (1)
         'eg. 3-mth average is not 3-lags but current and 2-lags.
         sdate1 = syy & fnc.numtext(smm)
         'start date for query (begining of lag value including average period)

         Set MyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
         MySql = sql.sqlVSers(lmm, lyy, qtable, qcode, sdate1)
         'MsgBox (MySql)
         MyRecordset.Open MySql, MyConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

         Do Until MyRecordset.EOF     'Loop to end and enter required values
         lag_value = lag_value + MyRecordset(qcode)
         MyRecordset.MoveNext
         Loop
         'Stop
         lag_value = lag_value / average_period
         MyRecordset.Close
     End If


     'STEP-B: Gets the current Value average or not.
     '===============================================================
         smm = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, average_period - 1, "mm")           'dating backwards to account for average period
         syy = fnc.lagdate(mm, yy, average_period - 1, "yy")           'dating backwards to account for average period
         sdate1 = syy & fnc.numtext(smm)
         'start date for query (begining of lag value including average period)

         Set MyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
         MySql = sql.sqlVSers(mm, yy, qtable, qcode, sdate1)
         MyRecordset.Open MySql, MyConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

         Do Until MyRecordset.EOF     'Loop to end and enter required values
         cur_value = cur_value + MyRecordset(qcode)
         MyRecordset.MoveNext
         Loop

         cur_value = cur_value / average_period
         MyRecordset.Close


     'STEP-C: Calculates the Requested % Change or Point Value.
     '===============================================================
     If compare_period = 0 Then
         ValueV = cur_value
     Else
         ValueV = cur_value / lag_value * 100 - 100
     End If

 End Function
```

Since I totally bypass the use of a subroutine, the connection to the database is currently done as a workbook helper routine as shown below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Dim filePath
filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
If Right$(filePath, 1) <> "\" Then filePath = filePath & "\"
MyConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & filePath & "rsdata.accdb;"
End Sub
```

Problem is, this updating process is less than desirable. Idealy, I would like to position a custom button inside the menu bar that (upon clicking it) will connect to the database and recalculate all the userdefined functions that are used in a given worksheet or workbook.

Please offer your suggestions or point to where something like this may have been done before.

Thanks in advance. 
JR.

Comment: One way to "control" this is by defining a global variable (e.g. Recalc = True/False) or named cell. Set the variable through a user interaction.  It is difficult to control when to set the variable back to False though (can't be part of the UDF, unless you count that every cell with a UDF has been recalculated)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `UDF`'s for something they are not designed to do.  What they *are* designed to do is behave just like other cell formula, and be calcutaed when Excel decides they need to be.

You have two options

- redesign your application to not use `UDF`'s (IMO the best way)
- modify your `UDF`s to only respond to a trigger specified by you, eg a button click (IMO a cludge and generally bad idea)

How to redesign to avoid `UDF`'s depend on factors not disclosed in your OP